# What is $\sin(2)$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I understand that $\sin(2)$ is equal to $0.90929\ldots$. However, I am wondering if there is a simpler way of calculating this. Essentially I am wondering if there is an answer with this where $\pi$ is in there as an answer like $2\pi/6$ or something where it equals $0.90929\ldots$.

Comment: If [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2)) is any indication, there is probably not a closed form; or, if there is one, someone has yet to find one.

Comment: "a simpler way of calculating". Simpler than which way?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2) $\sin 2$ is transcendental.

Comment: like converting the number .90929 in forms of like pi over something. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan so basically there isn't any form of pi that it can be converted to?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, but I will check again.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan - While that's true, that doesn't mean there isn't a closed form. (Just moreso an indicator that finding one is probably a nontrivial exercise.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - I think to clarify OP's intent, he mostly wants a closed form: not appealing to approximations, series, integrals, other trig functions ... a closed form and an exact value. If that makes any sense?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan alright thank you!

Comment: Maybe half-angle theorem and triple angle theorem will work...

Comment: _Usually_, it is when you apply $\sin$ to rational multiples of $\pi$ that we get easily describable numbers out on the other end. I don't think it ever works the other way (except for $\sin(0)$). I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Arthur I feel like there is, however it's been a long time since I took precalculus so I honestly don't remember. But like Mohammad said that there could not be one.

Comment: My stupid self was searching for $\sin 2^\circ$!

Comment: $\sin 2=\frac{2\pi}{6}$ is pretty unlikely, as $\frac{2\pi}6>1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it was just an example in a term of what I was looking for an answer type. I didn't mean it literally...

Comment: @AdanVivero: I know ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sine function is transcendental, which means that generally, you cannot find a "simple" expression for $\sin(x)$. Nevertheless, you can approximate $\sin(x)$ (to which ever degree of precision you like) using [Taylor polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: Thank You! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The usual values of the sine and cosine functions are not expressions involving $\pi$ (the most familiar ones are $1,\frac12,\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt 3}2$). You probably confuse with the arguments being rational multiples of $\pi$, i.e. fractions of a full turn.

In fact, the sine and cosine of $q\pi$ are always algebraic numbers, as $\sin nx, \cos nx$ can be developed as polynomials of degree $n$ in $\sin x,\cos x$. It is also known that for $q\pi$ the only rational values of the sine are $0,\pm1$ and $\pm\frac12$. (Check Niven's Theorem).

For arguments that are not in this form, I am not sure that much is known. As coined by Mohammad Zuhair Khan, $\sin 2$ is a transcendental number. For the same reason as before (polynomial transformation), $\sin n$ and $\cos n$ where $n$ is a natural must be transcendental numbers.

I don't think that there is another way to express $\sin 2$ using a closed-form expression (but trivially, $\Im e^{2i}$). Numerical evaluation is not a big deal with the Taylor expansions

$$\cos x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}$$
$$\sin x=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$

For fast convergence, it is advisable to evaluate for a small power of $2$, say $2^{-8}$, then obtain the value for $2$ by successive doublings.